# Python tabula read_pdf opens java console window

Tags: python, pyinstaller, tabula

I have a script that uses tabula.read_pdf. Script works fine, however when I build an exe file with PyInstaller (with --noconsole option) and run my script - it opens java.exe empty console window which stays opened untill script work is done. 
How can I avoid it?
Thanks

Answer (score 4):

I was running into a similar issue and couldn't really find the wrapper.py. After some tinkering around I found a similar workaround:

Within the directory where tabula is installed "...\Lib\site-packages\tabula" edit the "io.py" file. In the "_run" function just change the "args" variable to use "javaw" instead of "java".

I was able to hide the java console when my .exe file ran this way. I hope this helps someone in the future.

Comment: I am coming from the "Future", thanks a lot, it helped me, thank you very much

Comment: + If you do not want to permanently change the "io.py" file: you can change it like described in this answer, run the Pyinstaller command, and then revert back once the Pyinstaller command is done building.

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to fix it by changing java to javaw in wrapper.py file. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of months ago I used the method described above (changing io.py) and it worked perfectly. But today I did not find these args in io.py but I found them in backend.py (same folder as io.py). You can find these args in the function call_tabula_java in the Class SubprocessTabula.