# Python Tabula Script keeps opening Java.Exe window. How do I get it to use jawaw.exe instead?

Tags: java, python-3.x, exe, tabula, javaw

I have made a python script that used tabula.read_pdf. After I convert it to an executable file, java.exe window keeps popping up when running tabula.read_pdf. Other threads indicate that I should use javaw.exe instead of java.exe. But how do I select this ?

I use auto-py-to-exe to make the executable file for my python script.

[Python tabula read_pdf opens java console window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55164352/python-tabula-read-pdf-opens-java-console-window)
In this question they talk about changing i name in a wrapper file.

Answer (score 0):

(Just copying my answer from the post you linked above) I was running into a similar issue and couldn't really find the wrapper.py. After some tinkering around I found a similar workaround:

Within the directory where tabula is installed "...\Lib\site-packages\tabula" edit the "io.py" file. In the "_run" function just change the "args" variable to use "javaw" instead of "java".

I was able to hide the java console when my .exe file ran this way. I hope this helps someone in the future.